# delete a specific line in txt file if it consist a special word

Tags: python, txt

i ask for a input, if that input was in a line of my txt file, delete just that line

```
w = input("Enter STnumber: ")
with open("student.txt ", "r") as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
     with open('student.txt','w') as f:
         for line in lines:
             if w in line :
                 # (i cant undrstand here)
```

these will clear all of my txt file
actually its a name , lastname and a number in the txt file, like this
jon sina 1234

if w = 1234, delete just the line with a number 1234

Comment: Does your code not work? Are you getting an error, warning, or unexpected behavior? If unexpected, what is supposed to be the output and what are you getting? Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your code does the exact opposite of your description

Comment: that was what i saw in google search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove lines from a text file that contain a certain pattern then you could do this:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r+') as foo:
    lines = foo.readlines()
    foo.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        if not 'Pattern' in line:
            foo.write(line)
    foo.truncate()
```